# I cant's left-click anything in the 3D viewport

Tags: error

When I open the Blender app.  I can’t left-click any object in the 3D-wiewport , and get this message.

[image: Start browser]

If I thoose the Boolean modifier I still not able to click on any object in the 3D-viewport but get the “operation menu” from the Boolean modifier.

[image: Boolean modefier]

I have tried to reinstall Blender but nothing changed.

What to do ???

Comment: can you please write the error. I can't see the error message clearly.

Comment: try right-clicking to select objects, see if that works.

Comment: can you please upload images that can be zoomed in